# How does one assign the same value to some elements of an array at once in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, assign

I'm interested in knowing how does one assign the same value to some elements, a row, or a column of an array at once in VBA? For instance, I have a 3x3 array (**MyArray**) like this

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

I need to change the value of elements **MyArray(1,1)**, **MyArray(2,2)**, **MyArray(1,3)**, and **MyArray(3,2)** with 11 or the value of row 2 with 13. Now, how to do those things by a single statement? I thought something like:

`Union(MyArray(1,1), MyArray(2,2), MyArray(1,3), MyArray(3,2)) = 11`

and

```
MyArray(2,1 : 2,3) = 13
```

would work, but an error occurred. The way I handle this thing is to put the data of the array on an unused worksheet, change the values there, and then read back the values from the worksheet into the array like [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38539987/3397819). Using the above examples, I then use the following codes:

```
Range("A1:C3") = MyArray: Range("A1,B2,C1,B3") = 11: MyArray = Range("A1:C3")
```

and

```
Range("A1:C3") = MyArray: Range("A2:C2") = 13: MyArray = Range("A1:C3")
```

Are there any other alternatives without using a worksheet or looping?

Comment: There is a way, but it won't work with bidimentional arrays. Do you need them to be bidimentional?

Comment: @EduardoPoço Did you mean a 2D array? Yes, I need it for a 2D array like the example above (MyArray)

Comment: Well, anyway... I was thinking about using strings and Split(), which returns an array, but this array won't be 2D. What about using an array of arrays? Instead of accessing with MyArray(i, j), it will be MyArray(i)(j).

Comment: @EduardoPoço No, I only need to modify a 2D array.

Comment: Seems you are going to modify the array a lot of times and need an easy way to do it, without loops nor relying on sheet operations, which are slow. Is that it?

Comment: @EduardoPoço Yes, that's it

Comment: Usually, there are better ways to optimize than using arrays. If you can, give more detail on what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBA as it is, does not support something like this. It is only possible with a range.

Theoretically....

You can do stuff like this using `Evaluate` in a verly limited way. To show some examples which change only one row/column or specific values of an 2d-array:

```
Dim MyArray() As Variant

Public Function MyArrayOut() As Variant
  MyArrayOut = MyArray
End Function

Sub testing()
  'we are using a 5x4 (4 columns / 5 rows) array
  ReDim MyArray(0 To 4, 0 To 3) As Variant 'also 1 to 5 and 1 to 4 are possible.... doesn't matter

  Dim i As Long, j As Long 'input some numbers
  For i = 0 To 4
    For j = 0 To 3
      MyArray(i, j) = i + 5 * j + 1
    Next
  Next

  [A1:D5].Value2 = MyArray
  Stop ' check the sheet -> should be 1 to 20

  'lets add 11 to the second row
  MyArray = Evaluate("=IF({0;1;0;0;0},MyArrayOut()+11,MyArrayOut())")

  [A1:D5].Value2 = MyArray
  Stop ' check again. row 2 should be 13, 18, 23, 28

  'set only 1,1 ; 2,2 ; 4,2 and 5,4 to 0. just keep in mind that using math will fail if ANY value is not numeric (or empty)
  MyArray = Evaluate("=MyArrayOut()*{0,1,1,1;1,0,1,1;1,1,1,1;1,0,1,1;1,1,1,0}")

  [A1:D5].Value2 = MyArray
  Stop 'A1, B2, B4, D5 all should be 0

  'set column 3 to "abc"

  MyArray = Evaluate("=IF({0,0,1,0},""abc"",MyArrayOut())")

  [A1:D5].Value2 = MyArray
  Stop ' check again. column C should be just abc

End Sub
```

Using a valid `IF`-statement allows to do a lot, but you need to either hardcode it, or a pretty complex algorithm which "kills" as good as allways the idea of "not looping".

Also this will take more resources and be as good as always slower than doing it directly. Also you need an extra function to bring the array inside the evaluate.

Still there is one case where it is useable to my eye: Extracting one row/column via `INDEX`. Keep in mind, that the output is still a 2d-array which can be nulified via the `Application.Transpose`-Trick. The reason for it being useable is just the fact, that there is no need to know the size of the array. This way you can directly extract via `extrVar = Evaluate("=INDEX(MyArrayOut(),2,)")`. While the 2 could be set via a different varianble. This way you do not need to `ReDim` the new variable (`extrVar` in this case). It just needs to be variant. That said, with `Application.Index` you also could achive this without the use of `Evaluate`. (Which also uses less resources and is faster)

I hope you got an idea of the way you *could* use evaluate to do the job.

Still, VBA itself doesn't offer any way to manipulate multiple contents of an array in one step by the syntax itself. (At least not in a way you could use for this case)

**EDIT**
I almost forgot: to set ALL values in a variable to the same value, something like `MyArray = Evaluate("=IF(MyArrayOut()="""",5,5)")` will do set everything to 5 or `MyArray = Evaluate("=IF(MyArrayOut()="""",""abc"",""abc"")")` to only contain "abc". To empty it out, you could use `MyArray = Evaluate("=IF(MyArrayOut()="""","""","""")")` but a simple `ReDim` without `Preserve` also could do it in one line.

**EDIT 2**

for your `Range("A1:C3") = MyArray: Range("A1,B2,C1,B3") = 11: MyArray = Range("A1:C3")` example, you could use it as a base for a own function like:

```
Public Sub multiSetSame(ByRef arr As Variant, ByVal val As Variant, ParamArray str() As Variant)
  Dim runner As Variant
  For Each runner In str
    arr(Split(runner, ",")(0), Split(runner, ",")(1)) = val
  Next
End Sub

Sub test()
  Dim MyArray(1 To 3, 1 To 4) As Long

  multiSetSame MyArray, 11, "1,1", "2,2", "1,3", "3,2"

  [A1:D3].Value2 = MyArray
End Sub
```

But also for this example, while I dont know how it is evaluated *which* values to change, it either should be better to directly change it as they are evaluated, or if they are always the same, just write a sub which does the job for all the values. Any "workaround" will just slow down the whole process.

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)

Comment: Seems like Worksheet.Evaluate is about two times faster than Application.Evaluate https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/

Comment: Thank for the elaborate answer. I really appreciate it. For now, I'll accept this answer. I might have questions in the future. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

VBA doesn't offer any way to assign a multi-dimentional array in a single statement, so you'll need to declare the array and then assign each value:

```
Dim MyArray(2,2)

MyArray(0,0) = 1
MyArray(0,1) = 2
MyArray(0,2) = 3
MyArray(1,0) = 4
MyArray(1,1) = 5
MyArray(1,2) = 6
MyArray(2,0) = 7
MyArray(2,1) = 8
MyArray(2,2) = 9
```

**EDIT**
An earlier version of Slai's answer had a partial solution which I've fleshed out to a solution that avoids using jagged arrays.

It turns out you can assign a 2D array in a single statement, but the array *must* be Variant and 1-based, and it *only* works in Excel.

You can assign individual elements, and you can use a CopyMemory trick to assign an entire "column" (but *only* the first column). If you need to assign entire "rows" or "columns", then you might be better off with a jagged array.

```
Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
    lpvDest As Any, _
    lpvSource As Any, _
    ByVal cbCopy As Long)

Sub test()
    'assign a 2D array using the [] shorthand syntax for Eval
    myArray = [{1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9}]

    'Change an individual value
    myArray(1, 2) = 11

    'Change the entire first row (this ONLY works for the first row)
    'Using a 1-based array assigned with []/Eval
    colarray = [{14,15,16}]
    CopyMemory myArray(1, 1), colarray(1), (UBound(colarray, 1) - LBound(colarray, 1) + 1) * 16 ' changes a whole "column"

    'Change the entire first row (this ONLY works for the first row)
    'Using a 0-based array assigned with Array()
    colarray = Array(17, 18, 19)
    CopyMemory myArray(1, 1), colarray(LBound(colarray, 1)), (UBound(colarray, 1) - LBound(colarray, 1) + 1) * 16 ' changes a whole "column"

End Sub
```

Comment: I know Documentation is new and all, but is there a policy for it with regards to just linking out an answer? My gut says to follow the same rules as external links; keep a link to the source, but quote out the relevant passage

Comment: I couldn't find any way on the cited link to implement the task. Could you post your code instead? Thanks.

Comment: @Etheur Yes, I just clarified that in chat. Should have posted in comments. Updated the answer

Comment: Thank for the answer. I appreciate it. (+1)

Comment: @ThunderFrame - See the answer provided by Slai - you can initialize a 2d array in a single statement - it is his first example.... perhaps you can edit your answer.

Comment: Slai changed his answer in response to my comments, but I've fleshed out his idea and credited Slai with the original idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand your question, so I concentrate on the questions's title

> How does one assign the same value to some elements of an array at
>   once in VBA?

I don't use VBA so I'm not sure but before Ruby I used VbScript a lot, here an example how to do this in VbScript. I have never crossed a VbScript codepiece that doesn't run in VBA (the other way around I did), but who knows..

```
MyArray = array(_
array(1, 2, 3),_
array(4, 5, 6),_
array(7, 8, 9)_
)

Wscript.echo MyArray(0)(0) '1'
Wscript.echo MyArray(2)(2) '9'
```

EDIT: as Dirk remarks: this solution is a single dimension array with other arrays in it, but as my solutions shows it's often more versatile, it doesn't need to be initialised for example..

Comment: first off: a 1d-array inside another 1d array is NOT a 2d-array!

Comment: Thank for the answer. I appreciate it. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid writing for-loops every time you need to assign values in a defined pattern, as I understand the problem, you will have to implement a Sub like this:

```
SetArray(MyArray, patternStr, value)
```

patternStr is the string that will be parsed and tell the Sub where to put the value. Some possibilites are:

"r1" - value goes to all columns in row 1

"c2" - value goes to all rows in column 2

"all" - value goes to all elements

"3,2 1,1" - value goes to (3,2) and (1,1)... if it is a 3x3 matrix, maybe you will want to ommit the commas in the pattern

You will have to implement this with some VBA code, at least once, and then it will be possible to call it many times without much effort and in a very easy to understand the calling code.

You may want to implement the parser in a way that strings concatenated with spaces, like "r1 c2", do all the individual distributions.

Then, your example becomes:

```
SetArray(MyArray, "1,1 2,2 1,3 3,2", 11)
```

## EDIT1

It is also possible to wrap the array in a custom class instance, so that the calls become shorter:

```
Set aw = New MyArrayWrapper
MyArrayWrapper.array = MyArray

aw.SetArray("1,1 2,2 1,3 3,2", 11)
aw.SetArray("r1 c2", 12)
```

I will edit if it's not clear yer. Hope it helps!

Comment: This will not work the way you think. You would need to split the string mutiple times to get all "addresses" and then loop them. You should at least show the code which does the job instead of **"You will have to implement this with some VBA code"**. Sorry, but to my eye, this is not an answer. It is like offering a "cell color" for a formula-problem.

Comment: That's because the OP knows the for-loop answer and just don't want to use it many times. If thats not the case, I will post some code.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I appreciate it. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a language that can do that with rectangular arrays, but it can be a tiny bit easier with array of arrays:

```
MyArray = Array( [{1, 2, 3}], [{4, 5, 6}], [{7, 8, 9}] )
MyArray(0)(1) = 11 
MyArray(1) = [Column(A1:A3)*0+13]   ' changes a whole "row" to 13
MyArray(2) = MyArray(1)             ' copies one row to another
```

The disadvantage (or advantage) of jagged arrays is that each array can have different size (number of elements) or even be `Nothing`.

Comment: array is a reserved word in VBA and can't be used as a variable name

Comment: Thanks ThunderFrame, I could not try it before posting.

Comment: Under Excel 2016, MyArray ***is*** a 1-based 2D array (not jagged), so `myArray(1)(2) = 11` causes error, but `myArray(1,2) = 11` will work, but because it's not jagged, `myArray(1) = [{13,13,13}]` fails with `Subscript out of range`

Answer (score -2):

Use a for loop to assign the same value to multiple variables:

```
myArray[valueOne, valueTwe, valueThree];

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {           
    myArray[i] = true;          
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken. But this answer seems to not use VBA.